# MFMailComposeViewController action sheet is off-screen when setStatusBarHidden:YES on iOS5

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

I got the problem with the cancel button of MFMailComposeViewController. Here is my context

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}

- (IBAction)showButtonDidTouch:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
         MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
         mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
         mailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
         [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
         [mailViewController release];
}
}
```

I hid status bar at viewDidLoad and then called displayed mailViewController as present modal view controller. However, the problem is when the app in landscape mode and uikeyboard appears, the action sheet doesn't show up when cancel button is tapped as image: http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/5489/screenshot20120514at114.png

The little red image at top-left corner is the action sheet. If I set statusbarhidden = NO, it shows up.

I appreciate your help, thank you

Comment: Soo.... what's the question? Where would you expect the action sheet to be?

Comment: ah, the problem is the action sheet was off-screen and you can't tap it. I expect it appears normally, that means right above or below the cancel button. It just happens on iOS5 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue (which I see as an iOS bug) by registering for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification. Whenever the keyboard is shown, I manually set the frame of my MFMailComposeViewController's superview to +/- 20 (status bar height), depending on the orientation (landscape left or right). This is a pretty ugly hack, but it works for me for now.

Comment: thank you for the workaround. I didn't hide the status bar because of this issue, but now I have to hide it. And yours saves my day

Answer (score -1):

I used a timer,move

```
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:^(void) {}];
```

to outside of actionsheet,and it work too.